# Get Validation result by group

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is Three Validation Group A,B and No Group.

How to get validation result of only the specific validation group.

If Group A and No Group is not valid but all of group B is valid, i would like to get result as valid.

I have read the article validation in depth but don't find the straightforward solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Is there any simpler solution than this

```
    protected bool IsGroupB_Valid()
    {
        var validators = Page.GetValidators("B");

        foreach (IValidator item in validators)
        {
            if(item.IsValid == false)
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq will make it look better:

```
protected bool IsGroupB_Valid()
{
    return Page.GetValidators("B").All(v => v.IsValid);
}
```

But probably you should look for something really different